# Rails 3 - routing for admin section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, routes, admin

the structure of my admin section looks like this:

```
controlers -> admin -> admin_controllers...
views -> admin -> users -> data
views -> admin -> settings -> data
```

My `routes` looks like:

```
resources :users, :user_sessions
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

**EDIT**

```
  namespace :admin do
    ...      
    resources :users, :user_sessions
    match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
    match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  end
```

But if I set up to the browser url address `admin/login`, so I will receive an error about missing template (especially `Missing template user_sessions/new`). How is it possible? What  I forgot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to use namespaces, you have to use such shema:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users, :user_sessions
end
```

all that views should be in app/views/admin/, like this

```
app/views/admin/users/new.html.erb
```

the API details is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: and that's the strange - I have it so.

Comment: what's your admin's controller names? do you follow Ruby name conventions: **Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController**?

Comment: actually you better to use your own Admin's Application Controller to nest scoped controller from